# PHP Date() does not match timezone set in php.ini

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a server that needs to use EST time. I have set the date.timezone =  America/New_York in my php.ini, and then confirmed this using phpinfo(); I do indeed see date.timezone and default timezone show America/New_York in my phpinfo().

When I try to echo the date() with PHP via the terminal, I get back a time in PST instead of EST (3 hours behind):

```
php -r "echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');"
```

The server time was initially set to America/Los_Angeles, so I updated that and rebooted the machine. Now when I ask the server for the time, I get the time in EST as expected:

```
date
```

So now the server timezone AND the php.ini timezone are both set correctly, yet the PHP date() function still gives me a time that is 3 hours behind. I'm echoing this from the terminal so I'm positive it's not anything in my PHP project files themselves.

What could be causing this?

Comment: "PHP via the terminal, " most php installations have 2 php.ini's one for the command line php one for the web server. so check that. `php -i` on the command line

Comment: Try `php -i | grep timezone` for what rtfm is suggesting

Comment: @Jim good idea to grep, i would just scroll myself :-)

Comment: How about `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York')` during runtime? Does it impact it?

Comment: @Scuzzy Better to set it in `php.ini` when access is given.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Set date.timezone In php.ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451719/cannot-set-date-timezone-in-php-ini-file)

Comment: @rtfm your suggestion about the different php.ini for the terminal was spot on, I completely forgot that these were different. The PHP application is now showing the correct time. Please add this as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @localheinz of course, but for the purpose of debugging it might help.